# R: plot dates in specific locale

Tags: r, plot, locale

I build a vector `d` of POSIXlt dates. I make a `plot(d, x)` using this vector as axis x. but on the plot dates are printed using my computer's locale. I need them to use different locale. how can i choose the format/locale to be used on plots?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code or picture?

Comment: @Soheil i added the picture

Comment: It looks like a coursera question. If you simply want to get rid of the local timezone, you can do it like this `as.POSIXct(df$date,tz = "GMT")`, the `tz=` will set the timezone appropriately. For other timezones check the help for `as.POSIXct`

Comment: You need to pass the timezone in the format of `Continent/City`. The complete list of accepted timezones are given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: please provide reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use on Unix based system:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US");
```

This works for me:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","ru_RU")

df = data.frame(date=c("2012-02-01", "2012-02-01", "2012-02-02")) 
df$day <- weekdays(as.Date(df$date))
df$value <- c(1,10,5)

plot(df$value, xaxt="n") 
axis(side=1, labels=df$day, at=c(1,2,3))

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","en_US")

df = data.frame(date=c("2012-02-01", "2012-02-01", "2012-02-02")) 
df$day <- weekdays(as.Date(df$date))
df$value <- c(1,10,5)

plot(df$value, xaxt="n") 
axis(side=1, labels=df$day, at=c(1,2,3))
```

Comment: doesn't work. `Sys.getlocale()` doesn't return english so calling this results in `OS reports request to set locale to "en_US" cannot be honored`

Comment: Edited with example.. if you provide sample code I will try to recreate