# Convert date into specific locale format in R

Tags: r, date

I have to convert date col into specific format.

```
    structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), hour = 0:4, mday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L), wday = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), yday = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), isdst = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", 
"year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC")
```

the output should be:

```
1. januar 2014
1. januar 2014
1. januar 2014
1. januar 2014
1. januar 2014
1. januar 2014
```

It is in Danish. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553466/r-plot-dates-in-specific-locale) helped understand part of the problem. 
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `sub("^0", "", format(df1, "%d. %B %Y"))`  assuming that the locale is in Danish

Comment: damn, I have been trying to figure this out for past half an hour and decided to ask a question, and fugured out an answer in the mean time. also, I am not in dansh locale.  sub("^0", "", format(df$date, "%d. %B %Y")) %>% 
    tolower()

Comment: You can change the locale using `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","da_DK.UTF-8")`